# Pandas won't import (Python3.5) (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have installed pandas, numpy, and matplotlib using pip3. Importing numpy and matplotlib is successful, but importing pandas results in the following error.

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xa
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xa
```

If I uninstall matplotlib and import only pandas and numpy, they successfully import.

I have installed these packages in python2.7 and they are all able to import.

I am running the most recent version of Raspbian.

Comment: can you `pip3 show <module>` your modules and their versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling matplotlib and pandas using

```
sudo pip3 uninstall <module>
```

Then I installed pandas using:

```
sudo pip3 install -U pandas
```

and then installed matplotlib again using:

```
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```